# Setting Validation error for DataGrid/DataGridRow from code behind

Tags: validation

I have a datagrid with row level validation rule. What I want to do is while saving the record if there is error then attach the error description with the same row. (And obviously the template will then make that row highlighted due to the style of DataGridRow.)

Before saving I also want to check if there is error in datagrid. If it is I don't want to save it. (I know I can make the button disabled but I don't want that, I just want the save to not procced furthur). I created a dependencyproperty for this: IsError and was trying to set it to true in xaml if HasError is true.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource RowStyle}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
                            <!--<Setter Property="{Binding Path=IsError, ElementName=EditPreloadMessageLogWindow, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True"/>-->
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

But it didn't work. Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Imad.